# Transform row wise postgres data to grouped column wise data

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a stock market data which looks likes like

```
instrument_symbol|close |timestamp          |
-----------------|------|-------------------|
IOC              |134.15|2019-08-05 00:00:00|
YESBANK          | 83.75|2019-08-05 00:00:00|
IOC              |135.25|2019-08-02 00:00:00|
YESBANK          |  88.3|2019-08-02 00:00:00|
IOC              |136.95|2019-08-01 00:00:00|
YESBANK          |  88.4|2019-08-01 00:00:00|
IOC              | 139.3|2019-07-31 00:00:00|
YESBANK          |  91.2|2019-07-31 00:00:00|
YESBANK          | 86.05|2019-07-30 00:00:00|
IOC              | 133.5|2019-07-30 00:00:00|
IOC              |138.25|2019-07-29 00:00:00|
```

I want to transform it to

```
timestamp,           IOC,     YESBANK
2019-08-05 00:00:00  134.15   83.75
2019-08-02 00:00:00  135.25   88.3
......
.....
...
```

format.

Is there some Postgres query to do this? Or do we have to do this programmatically?

Comment: just pivot: `df.pivot('timestamp','instrument_symbol','close')`

Comment: removing pandas tag: the question is for `Postgresql`

Comment: Pivot (or crosstab) is much better done in the application. SQL isn't really designed to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  In Postgres, I like the `filter` syntax:

```
select "timestamp",
       max(close) filter (where instrument_symbol = 'IOC') as ioc,
       max(close) filter (where instrument_symbol = 'YESBANK') as yesbank
from t
group by "timestamp"
order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: What if I have n number of instrument symbols? should I list it one by one?

Comment: @AsnimPAnsari . . . If you know what they are, then yes.  Otherwise you need to use dynamic SQL . . . or perhaps arrays if that meets your need.

Comment: I want it to be dynamic. As the fields may change & i dont want to hardcode it every time

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
select "timestamp" :: date, max( case 
                         when instrument_symbol = 'IOC' 
                        then close end ) as ioc,
                   max( case 
                         when instrument_symbol = 'YESBANK' 
                        then close end ) as yesbank FROM t
                        group by "timestamp" :: date
                        order by 1 desc
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b2c4392399a1975c77a1460bce66e12f)